# How to filter dimensional array in React

Tags: arrays, filter

I have a dimensional array like this

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "file",
      "value": "File",
      "childs": [
        {
          "value": "New",
          "status": 1
        },
        {
          "value": "New",
          "status": 2
        },
        {
          "value": "New",
          "status": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "file",
      "value": "File",
      "childs": [
        {
          "value": "New",
          "status": 1
        },
        {
          "value": "New",
          "status": 2
        },
        {
          "value": "New",
          "status": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to filter items and own childs by childs.status

Comment: what do you want to filter items by, or do you just want to filter the `childs` array within each item?

Comment: For example my obj is this https://jsonblob.com/afd232ee-cf6e-11e7-8a13-b1abaea97fa1. the result I'm trying to filter by status == 3 https://jsonblob.com/ffe92147-cf6e-11e7-8a13-dd36b95f38fd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've setup a repl in which i've drawn out the method to filter your json. You can [find it here](https://repl.it/@raghudevan/DiscreteAdolescentWildcat); feel free to play around with it.

@younel's answer mutates the original array, I've also  updated my repl with his approach to show how the original json is mutated.

### Essence

- look through each item in `items`
- if a child in `item` matches the filter criteria, then keep the item and the filtered children

Comment: thank you. Yes other solution is mutates the original array.

Comment: @fanatikhamsi But you should specify this in your question, we are all here to help

Comment: @YouneL thanks you to. Your solutions is right for me and wil use it another component in app, other solution is the best on page

Comment: @fanatikhamsi please consider marking the answer as useful if you found it so :)

Comment: @RaghudevanShankar marking the best answer icon 25 mins ago :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method in order to filter your array of items based on specific test,  in your case when status 3 has been found, Here is a working example:

```js
var json = {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "file",
                "value": "File",
                "childs": [
                    {
                    "value": "New",
                    "status": 1
                    },
                    {
                    "value": "New",
                    "status": 2
                    },
                    {
                    "value": "New",
                    "status": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "file",
                "value": "File",
                "childs": [
                    {
                    "value": "New",
                    "status": 1
                    },
                    {
                    "value": "New",
                    "status": 3
                    },
                    {
                    "value": "New",
                    "status": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
    
var result = json.items.filter(function(item) {

    item.childs = item.childs.filter( function (child) {
        return child.status === 3;
    });
    
    return item.childs.length > 0;

});

console.log({items: result});
```

Comment: I believe this mutate the original array? OP might not want to mutate the original.

Comment: please take a look at my [repl](https://repl.it/@raghudevan/DiscreteAdolescentWildcat), your approach does mutate the original json; more specifically, it changes the `childs` attribute within each item.